# "Align Columns" in TeXstudio doesn't recognize \cmidrule as a rule

Tags: texstudio

I love the "Align Columns" feature in [TeXstudio](https://sourceforge.net/projects/texstudio/) to align tabular code. However, when I use `\cmidrule` from the [`booktabs`](https://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs?lang=en) package, "Align Columns" treats the command as part of the first cell, causing it to become huge.

e.g. instead of this (desired):

```
\begin{tabular}{cc}
    \toprule
    a & b \\
    \cmidrule(rl){1-1}\cmidrule(rl){2-2}
    1 & 2 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

we get this (actual):

```
\begin{tabular}{cc}
    \toprule
                       a                    & b \\
    \cmidrule(rl){1-1}\cmidrule(rl){2-2}
    1 & 2 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

Is there any way to get TeXstudio to treat `\cmidrule` like other `*rule` / `*line` commands, so it is ignored during "Align Columns"?

Answer (score 2):

Why yes, there is!

Go to:

`Options` > `Configure TeXstudio` > `Adv. Editor` > `Table Formatting` > `Special Commands`

and add:

`\cmidrule, \cmidrule(rl), \cmidrule( ...`

Unfortunately, you need to add all `(*)` variants you use, since each case is treated as a separate command.

Note: full credit [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/601/), I am only reposting Q & A here to help future users!